# "Cannot complete this action. Please try again" error in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am getting the error

> Cannot complete this action. Please try again

while creating site collection in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Can you check for details in the ULS log: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210652.aspx

Comment: @RobertLindgren "Monitorable A large block of literal text was sent to sql.  This can result in blocking in sql and excessive memory use on the front end.  Verify that no binary parameters are being passed as literals, and consider breaking up batches into smaller components.  If this request is for a SharePoint list or list item, you may be able to resolve this by reducing the number of fields."